# getting multiple errors when using HtmlUnit WebClient.getPage

Tags: java, webclient, htmlunit

I am trying HtmlUnit for the first time. I am developing on Linux Mint 17.1.
I am new to Java as well. I installed jenkins-htmlunit and my java environment is java-7-openjdk-amd64.

**I found the following example:**

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class myClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }    
}
```

**However, after executing the following shell commands:**

> javac -cp "/usr/share/java/*" myClient.java export
>   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/* java myClient

**I get the following errors:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable.getPrototype(SimpleScriptable.java:247)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable.makeScriptableFor(SimpleScriptable.java:217)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.getScriptObject(DomNode.java:790)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.setAndExecuteReadyState(HtmlScript.java:457)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:212)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:238)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:699)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:657)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
>     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:901)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:350)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:304)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:134)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:101)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:449)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:332)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:389)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
>     at myClient.main(myClient.java:8)

Comment: Your code works for me. What is the version of htmlunit that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me when using the latest snapshot build available. Please switch to the latest snapshot (there are some helpful details on this page http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html).
If you have no special needs it is always a good idea to use the latest snapshot build because we are doing regular fixes based on user feedback.